# How to put a line upon using python

Tags: python

Hello i was trying to know how to convert this.

```
 0|13|16|16|3|"After MLG down and securely locked, a red light is illuminated \
n the flight deck. The possible causes are."        \
|out of adjustment sensor|wiring problem|shorted sensor|b|1| |zita-2686
```

into this

```
 0|13|16|16|3|"After MLG down and securely locked, a red light is illuminated the flight deck. The possible causes are." |out of adjustment sensor|wiring problem|shorted sensor|b|1| |zita-2686
```

can you help me, because i did not found anything similar

Comment: why n before the flight is missing in the final result

Comment: What is this supposed to be? Could you provide some more context please?

Comment: @dantechguy This is a string but i need all together in python and i was trying and none works

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to replace the new line character with nothing. Try any of the following.

```
string = string.replace("\r","");
or
string = string.replace("\r\n","");
or
string = string.replace("\n","");
or
re.sub(r'\s' , '\n', line);
```

Comment: none of then works i try all of these i dont know what is my problem but it's so extraing

Comment: Have you renamed the 'string' variable to the variable you used in your code? If so than there are no new lines in the string which it looks like there is.